# UIScrollView Controller in IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode5

I want to write code for the `UIScrollView` that scrolls the images on the iPhone screen.

Please provide me the guidance for that or a sample code.

Comment: What did you try? Post the code which shows the problem in your code.

Comment: Read the tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content .Do some search before posting the question on stackoverflow

Comment: stackoverflow is for problems and solutions over it not for ready-made solutions!!!

Comment: @NSS : i am just asking for the examples how we make it. not for ready-made solutions.. and i am just a beginner in iphone development.i just want some examples..

Comment: Its give and take nothing else

Comment: @Ankit: then simply google it..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are readymade solution for beginners to start at raywenderlich, github and cocoacontrolls, here is one gallery https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fgallery and if you search better you will find result what you need